# CSS - Max-width for fixed div element not working with padding

Tags: css

Been trying hard, but failed to understand why this works as expected (`div` no wider than `1300px`):

```
div.top_menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

while this does not (`div` some `100px` wider than `1300px`):

```
div.top_menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 92%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 4%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

Does anyone have a clue? Many thanks for your support.

Comment: Create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try setting `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same rules that apply to `width` also do apply to `min-width` and `max-width`:

> By default, the property defines the width of the content area. If box-sizing is set to border-box, however, it instead determines the width of the border area.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

This means, the padding and the border-width is NOT included in the overall width by default. You have to use `box-sizing` to use the given width as outer width (including the padding and border-width).

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing